# Sometimes I Can't read certain buttons

Tags: gnome, themes, navigation

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. The theme being used for appearance is Adwaita, except for icons (Gnome). The overall theme is OS X Capitan.

My problem is that on certain buttons, the text is too light to see. It can be seen here (as can my theme layout):

[image: button screenshot]

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool themes screenshot]

Sometimes the text on the button will appear when I hover over it but most times not.

Any ideas how to change it? (I'm not locked into the themes; just want to be able to see everything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual problem AND the solution. I realized the problem only concerned Firefox (v54). I had just started playing around with system themes after nine years of using Linux. There are some bits of info that are not clearly stated online, e.g., the GTK version that needs to be installed (in this case FF required a GTK 3.4 or higher). I know now many of the themes have both GTK2 and GTK3 but if you try using the older ones they don't, they're GTK2 and most how-to-do-it articles don't explain that.

So, with that in mind (and thanks to [James](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3031491&p=14754663#p14754663)) I switched to a GTK 3 theme and it works with FF and all is now well.